# how to make an html div expand when its children grow?

Tags: css, html, position

I have a main div which contains a table :

```
<div id="main_container"><table>
```

you can see the full code in:
http://jsfiddle.net/tF62u/

As you can see, the child table is wider than the div but it (the div) doesn't adjust accordingly.

Which definition am I missing here?

Comment: The effect you have obtained using only HTMl & CSS is amazing. Kudos for that

Comment: That's what `<div>`s should do always... And as nice as your effect is, it would be easier to tell what's going wrong if you only included the CSS necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Add `display:inline-block` to your div's CSS rules:

```
#main_container {
    font-size: 9px;
    border: solid 3px #faa;
    background-color: rgba(245, 255, 10, 0.12);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tF62u/5/)**

Comment: +1 for making that Fiddle have clean HTML.. :') 

on a serious note, what's better, inline-block vs display table? is there really a difference?

Comment: @MackieeE - `inline-block` has greater compatibility than `table`, but in this case the end result is not very different.

Comment: Table cells receive enough abuse as it is, without also putting random table styles on random elements. So inline-block is much better. (Not perfect though, see my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `#main_container` have a `display` of `table-cell`:

```
#main_container {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tF62u/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:table;` to your `#main_container`

http://jsfiddle.net/tF62u/4/

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to make the div float left. Floating elements are as wide as their contents, rather than as wide as the window.

```
#main_container {
    font-size: 9px;
    border: solid 3px gray;
    background-color: rgba(245, 255, 10, 0.12);
    float:left;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tF62u/3/).

Also make sure to `clear` this float afterwards, or other content that follows will be displayed to the right of the div if the window is wider than the table.
By the way, this also goes for `display:inline-block`; if you do that you will need to make sure that the div is followed by a block element.

Another solution, for this particular fiddle, would be to remove the div entirely and apply all the styles to the table. Of course that would only work if the table were all the content of the div...

Comment: Could you make that following element using `::after` just like the common clearfix solution does?

Comment: No, the ::after trick doesn't work on an element that itself is floating; it would only work to clear floating elements itside it. If you have an inner div that is floating, inside an outer div, you can clear the float with the outer::after, but not with inner:after